# howto struct a code? e.g. at the top all variables, then all methods and last all event handlers

Tags: coding-style

i'm currently working on a big projekt and i loose many time searching the right thing in the code. i need to get e.g. a method which makes someting special. so i scroll the whole code.

are there any common and effective methods to struct a file of code? e.g.
1. all global variables
2. constructor etc.
3. all methods
4. all event handlers

do you know common methods to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more usual to break large projects into several source files, with logically related functionality.  This helps with speeding up compilation and reducing coupling in your design as well as helping you navigate the code.

An example might be to have separate files for

- UI functionality
- helper classes (such as geometric/maths stuff)
- file I/O
- core functionality that connects the rest together

Design is a large topic, the book Code Complete by Steve McConnell might be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt use global variables :)

Try spreading things out over different classes and files. Maks sure each class has only one purpose, instead of 1 class that manages a whole lot of different tasks.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a sensible enough structure to me, what would really benefit you though is learning to use the tools you have available — whatever editor you're using it will have a search function, you can use that to quickly find what you're looking for.

Some editors will also include bookmarks too, and most offer a way to move back and forward through recent positions in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Seen this sort of things started, never seen it kept on under the pressure to turn out code though.

Basically my rule of thumb is, if I feel the need to do this, break the code file up.